# What's the best way to display a location notification in flutter that pops up at 6 pm on weekdays?

Tags: flutter, dart

I looked at [scheduled_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scheduled_notifications), but it seems I need to create and call a method that actually creates the notification. I am wondering if it is possible to create a scheduled notification without any user interaction.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_notifications or https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-readme-tab- should do that.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/android_alarm_manager might also be useful.